IntelliJ Java Does not Autocomplete on Static Methods
Why is Intellij Not autocompleting static methods on my classes? It autocompletes on non-static methods, but not static methods. How can I fix Intellij Settings?
public class TestData {

    public static int addData(int x ,int y) {
        return x+ y;
    }
}

I should see AddData Method above.


While yes, it is valid Java to call static methods on an instance, this is widely considered to be confusing to the reader. Inteliij is probably deliberately designed this way to deter you from doing this. That said, static members does show up in the completion list once you have filtered out all the instance members by typing.

Please check this comment from JB team: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000190530/comments/115000228624

Static Members show up if you reference them by Class-Name not by instance.

It's a static method, so it should be called as TestData.addData (even though Java allows you to call static methods on instances)
